# Concatenating the last three columns

Tags: python, twitter

I have made a dataset with columns as words and the rows are the occurrence of these words in a tweet. 
The last three words depict the sentiment of the tweet. 
I want to concatenate the last three columns into one in python.
I am not understanding how to proceed.

```
w1 w2 w3..... zzzpostive zzznegative zzzneutral
1  0  0 ..... 1         0           0
1  0  1 ..... 0         1           0
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using pandas:

```
df['new_column'] = df["zzzpostive"] + df["zzznegative"] + df['zzzneutral']
```